# Different ways of negating a float variable generate different assembly

Tags: c#, assembly, floating-point, x86-64

I have the following code:

```cs
public static float F(float n) 
{
    return -n;
}
```

which generates following **asm**:

```
Program.F(Single)
    L0000: push eax
    L0001: vzeroupper
    L0004: vmovss xmm1, [esp+8]
    L000a: vmovss xmm0, [Program.F(Single)]  ; remember this line
    L0012: vxorps xmm0, xmm0, xmm1           ; remember this line
    L0016: vmovss [esp], xmm0
    L001b: fld st, dword ptr [esp]
    L001e: pop ecx
    L001f: ret 4
```

on the other hand I have following snippet:

```cs
public static float G(float n) 
{
    return n * -1;
}
```

which generates:

```
Program.G(Single)
    L0000: push eax
    L0001: vzeroupper
    L0004: vmovss xmm0, [esp+8]
    L000a: vmulss xmm0, xmm0, [Program.G(Single)] ; remember this line
    L0012: vmovss [esp], xmm0
    L0017: fld st, dword ptr [esp]
    L001a: pop ecx
    L001b: ret 4
```

## Questions

- As you may noticed the outputs are a little bit different. Why do we have 2 different assemblies? Do the codes not perform exactly the same task?
- Is there a reason for such big chunk of assembly? If yes why?
- How can I get more efficient version of it.

### Note

The **NOTE**s are for the last question.

I want to get basically the "C" like assembly. E.g.:

```c
float 
f(float n) {
        return -n; 
}

float
g(float n) {
        return n * -1;
}
```

which generates:

```
f:
        xorps   xmm0, XMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        ret
g:
        xorps   xmm0, XMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        ret
.LC0:
        .long   -2147483648
        .long   0
        .long   0
        .long   0
```

- I tried following but it didn't work quite well:

```cs
public static unsafe float F(float n) 
{
    uint i = *(uint*)&n;
    
    i ^= 0x80000000;
    
    n = *(float*)&i;
    
    return n;
}
```

I got the following which I think is even less efficient:

```
Program.F(Single)
    L0000: sub esp, 8
    L0003: vzeroupper
    L0006: mov eax, [esp+0xc]
    L000a: mov [esp], eax
    L000d: mov eax, [esp]
    L0010: xor eax, 0x80000000
    L0015: mov [esp], eax
    L0018: vmovss xmm0, [esp]
    L001d: vmovss [esp+0xc], xmm0
    L0023: vmovss xmm0, [esp+0xc]
    L0029: vmovss [esp+4], xmm0
    L002f: fld st, dword ptr [esp+4]
    L0033: add esp, 8
    L0036: ret 4
```

- I made a silly mistake (see the comment). Forgot to switch `x64` mode:

Now we have an "efficient" assembly code:

```cs
public static float F(float n) 
{
    return -n;
}
    
public static float G(float n) 
{
    return n * -1;
}
```

```
C.F(Single)
    L0000: vzeroupper
    L0003: vmovss xmm1, [C.F(Single)]
    L000b: vxorps xmm0, xmm0, xmm1
    L000f: ret

C.G(Single)
    L0000: vzeroupper
    L0003: vmulss xmm0, xmm0, [C.G(Single)]
    L000b: ret
```

**BUT the 1st and 2nd question are valid I think:**

> Why do we have different ASM outputs here?

Comment: Returning a `float` via the x87-FPU stack, indicates that your compiler is in some form of 32-bit mode (I'm no C# expert, but your [mre] should also include all options you are passing to the compiler).

Comment: @chtz I can't believe that I forgot to check that. Thank you. 3rd question is answered.

Comment: Negating flips the sign bit with no regard to the data. Multiplying raises an exception if the operand is a signaling NaN. They are different operations.

Comment: @EricPostpischil why does C version have the same *asm* output?

Comment: The C standard does not require adherence to the IEEE 754 floating-point standard or support for signaling NaNs, and your C implementation chooses not to adhere, although it may use some IEEE 754 features.

Comment: An example where a NaN is not treated the same by `F` and `G` on the binary level, in this implementation: [tio.run (C# source encoded in URL](https://tio.run/##dY/BagIxEIbveYpBekhKd6n2uHhR6F5aKVTwUDykcSqBbbbMzC6K5Nm3UVcR0VzyM3xf/onjzLHruoZ9WMPnlgV/C8VixTtwlWWGD7VTf813lQb9/KeqrcCrPt7BQCIgHUJpKEAWChVvKuU9JcAjZMO91vMstF9o3gubs9BaAksEY5h4mdahRRKkvESZbAVZb0xx@fDDYJfor@dlfDqE4SmMTuFlGQcXxW3tV/BufdAmNaYCrivMF@QF33xAPdf9v/OZnRmT2m4x5RUTVey6fw)

Comment: Your compiler is insane for 32-bit code.  If it has to return in x87 `st0` anyway, use `fld` / [`fchs` (change sign)](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fchs).  No need for AVX instructions when you're just going to have to copy to x87 eventually.  If you didn't want to ask about all that cruft (or show everyone how terrible it is?), edit your question to just show the x86-64 versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output is different, for the simple reason that compiler does not 'think' like human but follows standard.

```
public static float F(float n) 
{
    return -n;
}
```

this means, ask compiler to **negate** `n` and return negated value.

And that's exactly what compiler does

```
vxorps xmm0, xmm0, xmm1    <--- change sign bit
```

```
public static float G(float n) 
{
    return n * -1;
}
```

This means to do **multiplication**, and that exactly what compiler does

```
vmulss xmm0, xmm0, [C.G(Single)] <--- multiply
```

In your world `(-n) == (n * -1)` but compiler has different opinion on that. And these 2 expressions are not same. So `(-n) != (n * -1)` and assembly outputs are different.

It's even worse than that, for float/double values `(a * b * c) != (c * b * a)`...

Well at least not by default, you could make it equal with special compiler flags, sorry don't remember what exactly they are.